# How to split string everywhere a letter appears?

Tags: python

I have a string containing letters and numbers like this -

```
12345A6789B12345C
```

How can I get a list that looks like this

[12345A, 6789B, 12345C]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> my_string = '12345A6789B12345C'
>>> import re
>>> re.findall('\d*\w', my_string)
['12345A', '6789B', '12345C']
```

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of completeness, non-regex solution:

```
data = "12345A6789B12345C"

result = [""]
for char in data:
    result[-1] += char
    if char.isalpha():
        result.append("")
if not result[-1]:
    result.pop()

print(result)
# ['12345A', '6789B', '12345C']
```

Should be faster for smaller strings, but if you're working with huge data go with regex as once compiled and warmed up, the search separation happens on the 'fast' C side.

Answer (score 0):

You could build this with a generator, too. The approach below keeps track of start and end indices of each slice, yielding a generator of strings. You'll have to cast it to list to use it as one, though (`splitonalpha(some_string)[-1]` will fail, since generators aren't indexable)

```
def splitonalpha(s):
    start = 0
    for end, ch in enumerate(s, start=1):
        if ch.isalpha:
            yield s[start:end]
            start = end

list(splitonalpha("12345A6789B12345C"))
# ['12345A', '6789B', '12345C']
```